# Can I use a 3.7 or 7.4v lithium ion battery to power 6 coin cell motors?

Tags: power-supply, dc-motor, lithium-ion, vibration-motor

I am doing a project that involves 6 coin cell motors. I am looking to use a lithium ion battery but I'm not sure of what voltage so I'm reaching out to see if anyone has advice.

Technical details on the coin cell motors:
Voltage: 2V - 5V
5V current draw: 100mA, 4V current draw: 80mA, 3V current draw: 60mA, 2V current draw: 40mA
11000 RPM at 5V

For more information on the project, there will only be 3 motors running at a time, and the strength of the motors can be changed using a potentiometer connected. I used PWM for this project so that not all 6 motors will be used at the same time.

Would I be able to use a lithium ion battery of some voltage to power these? Any advice would be appreciated, this is my first project and I am totally inexperienced. Thank you!

Comment: A coin cell battery is usually only 1.5V and is too small to produce 40mA or more. A Lithium battery is usually much larger and can power a few or thousands of the motors depending on the battery spec's and size.

Comment: @audioguru iirc coin cell motors are a description of the form factor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The motors will only pull the current they need, as shown by their voltage vs current graph (or the values you listed). You can connect them directly **to the 3.7~4.2V battery only** and their strength will change as the battery drains. You can use a series resistor like you would with an led if you want to limit the power drawn. Or you can connect them to a regulated circuit for a constant draw as well.

Connecting them directly to the 7.4V battery will probably fry the coils, so you must use a current limiting setup or regulate it down.